# Going to learn google app script for sheets. Is what I want to do with it even possible?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I recently asked [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/136509/filtering-multiple-ranges-into-a-single-list), but there were no satisfactory answers, so I am turning to learning google scripts to do that plus the following, and I wanted to know if either or both were possible using scripts with google sheets:

I have a set of conditions that I filter data on and I want to have those conditions to have a state, either ENABLED or DISABLED. If a condition is enabled, then I want to filter the data with consideration of that condition along with any other enabled conditions (i.e. just like a standard fliter() would). If a condition is disabled, then the condition is not evaluated when filtering the data.

The idea is that I can set the ENABLED / DISABLED state in the sheet then run the function to filter the data accordingly.

The reason I am looking into this and the linked question is because I have to run this type of filtering on a large number of data sets and I am currently doing so much copying and pasting and editing filter() formula syntax that I feel like time would be better spent automating things.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tl;Dr: Yes, it's possible.

With Google Apps Script you could read/write Google Sheets data. To effectively use it you should know "some" programming, "some" JavaScript and apply "some" "spreadsheet thinking".

By "spreadsheet thinking" I mean that you should know how spreadsheets handle values and formulas, and understand how values (single and arrays) are handled.

Also could be helpful to know "some" HTML and CSS in case that you want to build custom HTML dialogs and/or a sidebar.

References

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets